# How to retain the untokenizable character in MaxEntTagger?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using MaxEntTagger for pos-tagging and sentence splitting by using the follwing codes:

```java
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("models/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Sentence<? extends HasWord>> sentences = MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(out2)));

for (Sentence<? extends HasWord> sentence : sentences) {
    content.append(sentence + "\n");
    Sentence<TaggedWord> tSentence = MaxentTagger.tagSentence(sentence);
    out.append(tSentence.toString(false) + "\n");
}
```

The problem is it will complain there are untokenizable characters in the text.  And the tagged output will omit those untokenizable characters.  So for example, the original text is: 
Let Σ be a finite set of function symbols, the signature.

where Σ is in big5 code.  But the program will show the following warning message:
Untokenizable: Σ (first char in decimal: 931)

and the tagged output is: 
Let/VB be/VB a/DT finite/JJ set/NN of/IN function/NN symbols/NNS ,/, the/DT signature/NN ./.

the splitted sentence I got is:
Let be a finite set of function symbols , the signature .

My question is how to retain these untokenizable characters?

I've tried modifying the mode's props file but with no luck:

```
  tagger training invoked at Sun Sep 21 23:03:26 PDT 2008 with arguments:
                    model = left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger
                     arch = left3words,naacl2003unknowns,wordshapes(3)
                trainFile = /u/nlp/data/pos-tagger/train-wsj-0-18 ...
                 encoding = Big5
            initFromTrees = false
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks Prof. Manning's help. But I encounter the same issue when utilizing parser tree.

### The sequel

I need to get the parser tree of a sentence, so I used the following codes:

```java
PTBTokenizer<Word> ptb = PTBTokenizer.newPTBTokenizer(new StringReader(sentences));            
List<Word> words = ptb.tokenize(); 
Tree parseTree2 = lp.apply(words); 
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack(); 
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory(); 
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parseTree2);
```

But I don't know how to set PTBTokenizer for resolving the issue of untokenizable characters this time.
If using the factory method to generate an PTBTokenizer object, I don't know how to concatenate it to the StringReader.

```java
List<Word> words = ptb.getTokenizer(new StringReader(sentences));
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The Stanford tokenizer accepts a variety of options to control tokenization, including how characters it doesn't know about are handled. However, to set them, you currently have to instantiate your own tokenizer. But that's not much more difficult than what you have above. The following complete program makes a tokenizer with options and then tags using it.

The "noneKeep" option means that it logs no messages about unknown characters but keeps them and turns each into a single character token. You can learn about the other options in the PTBTokenizer class javadoc.

**NOTE:** you seem to be using a rather old version of the tagger.  (We got rid of the Sentence class and started just using List's of tokens about 2 years ago, probably around the same time these options were added to the tokenizer.) So you may well have to upgrade to the latest version. At any rate, the code below will only compile correctly against a more recent version of the tagger.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.TokenizerFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

/** This demo shows user-provided sentences (i.e., {@code List<HasWord>}) 
 *  being tagged by the tagger. The sentences are generated by direct use
 *  of the DocumentPreprocessor class. 
 */
class TaggerDemo2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("usage: java TaggerDemo modelFile fileToTag");
      return;
    }
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(args[0]);
    TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> ptbTokenizerFactory = 
    PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "untokenizable=noneKeep");
    BufferedReader r = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[1]), "utf-8"));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "utf-8"));
    DocumentPreprocessor documentPreprocessor = new DocumentPreprocessor(r);
    documentPreprocessor.setTokenizerFactory(ptbTokenizerFactory);
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : documentPreprocessor) {
      List<TaggedWord> tSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
      pw.println(Sentence.listToString(tSentence, false));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, it helps me a lot!